# Categories and Subcategories Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories

So, I have categories, and subcategories that I'm trying to add to a project, I have tried to use awesome_nested_set gem, but cannot find where to put the actual category names.

I don't want users to be able to edit, update or delete any of the categories, or subcategories, I just want them as a drop down menu, so they can select the category and then subcategory and then have their selection added to a listing page.

My code so far:

This is in category.rb

```
    class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories
end

class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :parent_id, :null => true, :index => true
      t.integer :lft, :null => false, :index => true
      t.integer :rgt, :null => false, :index => true

      # optional fields
      t.integer :depth, :null => false, :default => 0
      t.integer :children_count, :null => false, :default => 0
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :categories
  end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_nested_set
end
```

This is in _form.html.erb partial for categories:

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Category, @category) {|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" } %>
```

So, my question is, where do I put the category names and how do I link them to subs?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited the end of the post

Answer (score 0):

It's ok. Whoever closes these things can go ahead and do so now. I found a youtube video that explained it.

It's not overly relevant to the question but the video is MacKenzie Child 12 apps in 12 Weeks job board video.... i don't have a link to it but it should come up in youtube search if you type that in.

I figured out my answer from watching him create categories for the various types of jobs he created.

Thanks again.